# "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" - Customized

Tags: administration, user-management, grant-login-access

We have more than one system administrator in our org. They are categorised by assigning them different profiles. I want the feature "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" in such a way that Users in Standard System Administrator Profile be able to log in as any user and Administrators in custom System Administrator profile can log in as any user except the users in Standard System Administrator Profile.

Please help me find a solution for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

How many users do you have? This may not be an ideal situation for you, but if your org is small enough you can have your non-standard system admin users grant login access to Administrators by going to **Setup | My Personal Information | Grant Login Access.**

Comment: We have enabled a feature "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" through salesforce support so all administrator will be having this login as permission without even giving access by grant login access.

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking "Manage Users" check box at user level.

Comment: If I uncheck it admins cant log into any user